# install openssl-devel on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, openssl

I am trying to install openssl-devel on a 64bit linux instance on ec2.  However, when I try to install it `sudo yum install openssl-devel` I get this error:

```
Error: Package: openssl-devel-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
       Requires: openssl = 1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1
       Installed: openssl-1.0.0i-1.41.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-updates/latest)
           openssl = 1.0.0i-1.41.amzn1
       Available: openssl-1.0.0a-10.13.amzn1.i686 (amzn-main)
           openssl = 1.0.0a-10.13.amzn1
       Available: openssl-1.0.0e-2.16.amzn1.i686 (amzn-updates)
           openssl = 1.0.0e-2.16.amzn1
       Available: openssl-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1.i686 (amzn-updates)
           openssl = 1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1
```

But, when I try to install openssl-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1 I get this response:

```
Setting up Install Process
Package matching openssl-1.0.0g-1.26.amzn1.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

The version of openSSL installed (1.0.0i-1.41.amzn1) will not let me change to the version I need that will allow me to install openssl-devel.  Any ideas on how to change the installed version or install a compatible openssl-devel?

Comment: Did you try to run first `yum upgrade` to make sure that everything is in place ?

Comment: `arch`? `yum repolist`? `rpm -qa --qf "%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n" | grep -i openssl`?

Answer (score 10):

You have both `x86_64` and `i686` versions of `openssl` installed, but they have different versions. Yum gets very confused when this happens.

To fix this, you need to get both versions in sync, or remove (and maybe reinstall, if needed) one of them.

**Option 1**: Sync

Updating *should* get your system into a reasonably sane state:

```
yum update
```

Install the package you really wanted:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

If this fails, move on to...

**Option 2**: Remove and reinstall

Remove the offending package:

```
rpm --nodeps -e openssl.i686
```

Install the package you really wanted:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

Install the previously removed package:

```
yum install openssl
```

Comment: Doing a 'yum clean all' before this is a good way to make sure you don't have any stale repo data also.